# Can't send test message with Firebase because there of "no test decives configured"

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a message to a single device using Firebase. In **Cloud Messaging > Compose notification**, in the first step y fill title and text, and then I click on **Send test message** button. In the pop-up I paste my device registration token, but **Test** button is disabled. I can read this message: **No test devices configured**.

[image: No test devices configured pop-up capture]

How can I solve this problem? Do I need to configure my device on Firebase?

Answer (score 16):

After you paste your token in the box, a + sign appears on the right - you need to click that and it then adds the token appropriately.

Not great UX, I had the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

"**[Add an installation id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lN3Q.png)**" is an input field. but it seems as a info field. I looked a screen for a long time and try to find where is the test id field.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31487105)